# image slider keyframing in css

Tags: html, css, keyframe

here is my css in the slideshow

```
    .slideshow figure {
position: relative;
width: 500%;
margin: 0;
left: 0;
animation: 10s slidey infinite; }
```

and here is my keyframe css

```
@keyframes slidey {
    0% { left: 0%;}
10% { left: 0%;}
20% { left: -100%; }
30% { left: -100%;}
40% {  left: -200%;}
50% { left: -200%;}
60% {  left: -300%; }
80% {   left: -300%;}
100% {   left: 0%;} }
```

my problem is, how do you make the image slider cycle back to the first picture without going back to the previous pictures **(i want the animation to  keeps going right when going back to the 1st image)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation: mymove 10s infinite;
    background-size: 200px 200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0%   {opacity: 0;}
    25%  {opacity: 1;  background-image:url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRjOqKI0kZG7nIV2w7AFRWfPUGiqeM0J26TbCp8irR1jZiNG556);}
    50%  {opacity: 0; }
    75%  {opacity: 1; background-image:url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREaFRkgZSFrksv7yCBWBpfCBE7_VOVmA3ORqy5mPxAUn2BAJIW);}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
    0%   {opacity: 0;}
    25%  {opacity: 1;  background-image:url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRjOqKI0kZG7nIV2w7AFRWfPUGiqeM0J26TbCp8irR1jZiNG556);}
    50%  {opacity: 0; }
    75%  {opacity: 1; background-image:url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcREaFRkgZSFrksv7yCBWBpfCBE7_VOVmA3ORqy5mPxAUn2BAJIW);}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of smoothly continuing the direction of sliding from the last image into the first again (and repeating infinitely). Unlike for opacity animations, an extra bridging image is needed for 'chaining' the last-first animation between each set of showings. Otherwise either a blank frame ends up being shown between image sets, or the image tray flies backward to the first image. In view of the repeated first image, animation targets and times then have to be set.

The keyframes suggest there are 3 images in the set. That makes a 'tray' of 4 images (with the first repeated), which is set to 400% width in total. Then set the 'viewbox' DIV element to the native size of the images, and with overflow: hidden. For the animation parameters, the following work:

```
.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* 'viewbox' - set size below to match native image height & width */
  width: 400px; height: 300px;
}
figure img {
  float: left; 
}
figure {
  position: absolute;
  /* 3 images in set + repeated first image = 4 x 100% */
  width: 400%; 
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-animation: slidey 10s infinite;
  animation: slidey 10s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slidey {
  0%  { transform: translateX(0%); }
  25% { transform: translateX(0%); }
  33% { transform: translateX(-25%); }
  58% { transform: translateX(-25%); }
  66% { transform: translateX(-50%); }
  91% { transform: translateX(-50%); }
  100%{ transform: translateX(-75%); }
}

@keyframes slidey {
  0%  { transform: translateX(0%); }
  25% { transform: translateX(0%); }

  33% { transform: translateX(-25%); }
  58% { transform: translateX(-25%); }

  66% { transform: translateX(-50%); }
  91% { transform: translateX(-50%); }
  /* Sliding animation of last image back to first image here 
     Then the tray resets to 0% X position at new zero time 
       to show first image statically again */
  100%{ transform: translateX(-75%); }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow">
  <figure>
    <img src="pic1.jpg" alt="Pic1">
    <img src="pic2.jpg" alt="Pic2">
    <img src="pic3.jpg" alt="Pic3">
    <!-- repeated first image to enable chaining of first & last images -->
    <img src="pic1.jpg" alt="Pic1">
  </figure>
</div>
```